# VBScript download link skipping save as dialog

Tags: c#, vbscript

I am working on a project where i download a file from a website with credentials using VBScript then i call this VBScript by C# program.
The issue is on the program run and the download dialog box appear with three options (open, save and save as) i want to automate this dialog by choosing save as and sending the file location as a parameter.
How could this be implemented either adjusting this in VBScript or in C# program?
The current VBScript code is:

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
objIE.Navigate "URL" 
While objIE.Busy 
WScript.Sleep 100 
Wend 
Set ipf = objIE.document.all.ttAuthUID 
ipf.Value = "USRNAME" 
Set ipf = objIE.document.all.ttAuthPWD 
ipf.Value = "PSWD" 
Set ipf = objIE.document.all.Submit 
ipf.Click 
While objIE.Visible 
Wend
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its absurdly easy to download a file in C#, why not do it there? You will have complete control.

Comment: Alex there is a problem when downloading the file using C#, it failed in downloading i tried all the options from WebClient with NetworkCredentials  to HttpWebRequest and casting the response.
Nothing is valid with this file.

Comment: I'd suggest asking the question about your initial problem instead of this one. It sounds like you've already implemented part of this in vb but you haven't posted the code.

Comment: @AhmedHATEM Does your vbscript program run in a browser or creates a instance of a browser object?

Comment: Create object of browser as follows:
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate "URL"
While objIE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
Wend
Set ipf = objIE.document.all.ttAuthUID
ipf.Value = "USRNAME"
Set ipf = objIE.document.all.ttAuthPWD
ipf.Value = "PSWD"
Set ipf = objIE.document.all.Submit
ipf.Click
While objIE.Visible
Wend

Comment: Please edit your question to post the properly formatted code in there. It is painfully hard to understand a code posted in comments.

Comment: Victor Moraes Done.